# Ruby equivalent of ReadString?

Tags: ruby, c++-cli

I'm working on a project with a "customer made" database. He developed a C++/CLI application that stores and retrieves his data from a binary file using the BinaryWriter.Write(String) and BinaryReader.ReadString() methods.

I'm no C++/CLI expert but from what I understand these methods use a 7-bits encoding of the first bytes to determine the String length.

I need to access his data from a rail application, anyone's got an idea of how to do the same think in ruby?

Comment: What do you mean a "7 bit encoding"? And BinaryReader and BinaryWiter are no c++ classes from the standard lib.

Comment: BinaryReader.ReadString Method: Reads a string from the current stream. The string is prefixed with the length, encoded as an integer seven bits at a time.

Comment: You mean Pascal strings? I doubt any string classes use Pascal strings.

Comment: Can you use his C++ code?  If so you could [extend the Ruby language](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html) with his custom parser.

Comment: @maerics: Will that work if this code isn't actually C++, but C++/CLI, which I'm pretty sure is the case?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: hmm, not sure.  If [IronRuby](http://www.ironruby.net/) can run Rails then maybe targeting that platform is an option.

Comment: I've corrected my question, it is C++/CLI, and no I can't access his code

Comment: C++ and Ruby can be friends if you make a wrapper for those classes. If you can build a shared library it's usually easier to link that in than to replicate the original build environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with raw binary data, you'll probably need to spend some time familiarizing yourself with the `pack` and `unpack` methods and their various options. Maybe what you're describing is a "Pascal string" where the length is encoded up front, or a variation on that.

For example:

```
length = data.unpack("C")[0]
string = data.unpack("Ca#{length}")[0]
```

The double-`unpack` is required because you don't know the length of the string to unpack until you do the first step. You could probably do this using a substring as well, like `data[1,length]` if you're reasonably certain you're not dealing with UTF-8 data.

Comment: That's what I was looking at doing, but I wanted to make sure there's no easier solution... Thanks

Comment: When someone sets you up with this turkey of a "database", no, usually there's no easier solution. The best way would be to use the original code in a library that Ruby uses *gently* but this is the second best approach. Be sure to unit test this aggressively.